# lighttpd gives 403 Forbidden with PHP file

Tags: php, fastcgi, lighttpd

I have a lighttpd server in a container running the `sebp/lighttpd` image (`lighttpd` on Alpine Linux). It can serve HTML files with no problems.

I am trying to set up PHP for this server. However, when I try to access a PHP file, it sends back a `403` Forbidden response.

In php.ini, `force_redirect` is set to 1.

In `lighttpd.conf`, `mod_fastcgi.conf` is included.

In mod_fastcgi.conf, the following configuration is used:

```
server.modules += ("mod_fastcgi")
fastcgi.server = ( ".php" =>
                    ( "localhost" =>
                        (
                            "socket" => "/tmp/php-cgi.socket" + var.PID,
                            "bin-path"  =>      "/usr/bin/php-cgi"
                        )
                    )
                )
fastcgi.debug = 1
```

I set the access log to `"/var/log/lighttpd/access.log"`, and the error log to `/var/log/lighttpd/error.log`, but nothing shows up in that folder. `lighttpd` is set as the owner of the folder.

`/usr/bin/php-cgi -v` returns `PHP 8.0.28 (cgi-fcgi)`.

Answer (score 1):

Something else might be rejecting the response, such as including "mod_staticfile" in `server.modules` list before "mod_fastcgi"

View your complete config as lighttpd sees it with

`lighttpd -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf -p`

Comment: Seems like the problem was solved, I ran your command, restarted the container one more time and it now it works. I have no idea why.